# Find column values that are a start string of given string.

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, database

I have a database table that contains URLs in a column.  I want to show certain data depending on what page the user is on, defaulting to a 'parent' page if not a direct match.  How can I find the columns where the value is part of the submitted URL?

Eg. I have www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/here.html; I would expect to see (after sorting on length of column value):

- www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/here.html
- www.example.com/foo/bar/baz
- www.example.com/foo/bar
- www.example.com/foo
- www.example.com

if all those URLs are in the table of course.

Is there a built in function or would I need to create a procedure?  Googling kept getting me to LIKE and REGEXP, which is not what I need.  I figured that a single query would be much more efficient than chopping the URL and making multiple queries (the URLs could potentially contain many path components).

Comment: Some PL/SQL procedure, for sure. But it is easy to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple turn around the "Like" operator:

`SELECT * FROM urls WHERE "www.example.com/foo/bar/baz/here.html" LIKE CONCAT(url, "%");`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef6ee/1

Comment: Wow, _head slap_!  I assume if I wanted to allow any protocol I would just concat an additional '%' before url, yes?  Although that may catch some unintended.